# How to search for particular fields in MongoDB, based on a field which has matched

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm using the C# driver to query a mongo DB. I am trying to create a method which searches the links between two of my objects.

I've created some link items like the following..

```
    "linkResults": [
        {
            "id": "5dc54231f8da9dcc9f62f399",
            "createdAt": "2019-11-08T10:23:45Z",
            "leftDatabase": "sampledb",
            "leftCollection": "donald",
            "leftId": "5d7a762786ce3502bd2afb5a",
            "rightDatabase": "test",
            "rightCollection": "samplecities",
            "rightId": "5d7f85efe9a1ec580afc73d1",
            "relationshipId": 1,
            "relationshipDescription": "address of"
        }
    ],
```

If an ID which matches the left ID is passed into a method, I want to search only the fields on the right side (and vice versa).

**here are the params which get passed into my method**

```
    public class ItemLinkParameters
    {
        public int Page { get; set; } = 1;
        public int PageLimit { get; set; } = 20;
        public string Id { get; set; } = null;
        public ICollection<string> Database { get; set; } = new List<string>();
        public ICollection<string> Collection { get; set; } = new List<string>();
        public ICollection<long?> RelationshipId { get; set; } = new List<long?>();
    }
```

**and here is what I've got so far, but it searches both sides at the moment**

```
        //THIS METHOD NEEDS TO EVALUATE WHETHER THE ITEM SUPPLIED IS ON THE LEFT OR RIGHT SIDE, THEN ONLY SEARCH THE OTHER SIDE
        internal async Task<ICollection<Link>> getItemLink(ItemLinkParameters parameters, string db, string collection)
        {
            //gets mongo connection string and database name from the
            //MongoDatabaseSettings class which gets it from appsettings.json
            var client = new MongoClient(_dbsettings.ConnectionString);
            var database = client.GetDatabase(db);

            //uses the name from MongoCollectionName variable, set by MongoDatabaseSettings.cs, again supplied from appsettings.json
            var _linkDocs = database.GetCollection<Link>(collection);

            var filter = Builders<Link>.Filter.Empty;

            if (parameters.Id != null)
                filter &= Builders<Link>.Filter.Eq(x => x.LeftId, parameters.Id) | Builders<Link>.Filter.Eq(x => x.RightId, parameters.Id);

            if (parameters.Database != null && parameters.Database.Count() > 0)
                filter &= Builders<Link>.Filter.In(x => x.LeftDatabase, parameters.Database) | Builders<Link>.Filter.In(x => x.RightDatabase, parameters.Database);

            if (parameters.Collection != null && parameters.Collection.Count() > 0)
                filter &= Builders<Link>.Filter.In(x => x.LeftCollection, parameters.Collection) | Builders<Link>.Filter.In(x => x.RightCollection, parameters.Collection);

            if (parameters.RelationshipId != null && parameters.RelationshipId.Count() > 0)
                filter &= Builders<Link>.Filter.In(x => x.RelationshipId, parameters.RelationshipId);


            // get data with paging
            var qry = _linkDocs.Find(filter)
                .Skip((parameters.Page - 1) * parameters.PageLimit)
                .Limit(parameters.PageLimit);

            var data = await qry.ToListAsync();

            return data;


        }
```

I know that the results are only actually returned from the database at the end, when I use my filter to query the database. So I can't get my head around how I would be able to evaluate which field has had a match before this. Am I on the right lines or does this need to be reworked completely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to get it working - here is my solution

```
internal async Task<ICollection<Link>> getItemLink(ItemLinkParameters parameters, string db, string collection)
        {
            //gets mongo connection string and database name from the
            //MongoDatabaseSettings class which gets it from appsettings.json
            var client = new MongoClient(_dbsettings.ConnectionString);
            var database = client.GetDatabase(db);

            //uses the name from MongoCollectionName variable, set by MongoDatabaseSettings.cs, again supplied from appsettings.json
            var _linkDocs = database.GetCollection<Link>(collection);

            var leftFilter = Builders<Link>.Filter.Eq(x => x.LeftId, parameters.Id);
            var rightFilter = Builders<Link>.Filter.Eq(x => x.RightId, parameters.Id);



            if (parameters.Database != null && parameters.Database.Count() > 0)
            {
                leftFilter &= Builders<Link>.Filter.In(x => x.RightDatabase, parameters.Database);
                rightFilter &= Builders<Link>.Filter.In(x => x.LeftDatabase, parameters.Database);
            }

            if (parameters.Collection != null && parameters.Collection.Count() > 0)
            {
                leftFilter &= Builders<Link>.Filter.In(x => x.RightCollection, parameters.Collection);
                rightFilter &= Builders<Link>.Filter.In(x => x.LeftCollection, parameters.Collection);
            }


            // get data with paging
            var filter = Builders<Link>.Filter.Or(leftFilter, rightFilter);

            if (parameters.RelationshipId != null && parameters.RelationshipId.Count > 0)
            {
                filter &= Builders<Link>.Filter.In(x => x.RelationshipId, parameters.RelationshipId);
            }

            var qry = _linkDocs.Find(filter)
                .Skip((parameters.Page - 1) * parameters.PageLimit)
                .Limit(parameters.PageLimit);

            var data = await qry.ToListAsync();

            return data;


        }
```